# solved - Asus doesn't resume after suspend

Tags: suspend, asus, bios, resume

ASUS UX303LN laptop suspends well, but boots instead of resuming: - i changed size of partition - nvidia or nouveau doesn't change anything, nor blacklist nouveau in grub - tried kernel 4,13, 4.14.41, 4.18 and 4.19 as well but no change

"acpi_sleep=nonvs" option in grub didn't work either

I am quite lost too... can anyone help ?

latest news:blacklisted mei and mei_me > doesn't make anything, finded out that Windows 10 was corrupted (dual boot), restored it, disabled IMEI, disabled/enabled hibernate in wondows,... discharged completely the battery, changed options (wake on lid, ..) in bios, changed to newer nvidia drivers, went back to nouveau.... Nevertheless i still get the problem, ..

Comment: Do you have an NVMe M.2 SSD installed?

Comment: Nope. But i recently changed the old HDD for a SSD...

Comment: Probably irrelevant if not NVMe, but what make and model of SSD did you just install?

Comment: Samsung 860 EVO (V NAND)

Comment: libata.force=nohrst doesn't make anything either...

Comment: You can try what works for my Samsung 960 Pro but not sure if it will help for 860 EVO: `acpiphp.disable=1`

Comment: Nope. Tried it but doesn't help

Comment: latest news:blacklisted mei and mei_me > doesn't make anything, finded out that Windows 10 was corrupted (dual boot), restored it, disabled IMEI, disabled/enabled hibernate in wondows,... discharged completely the battery, changed options (wake on lid, ..) in bios, changed to newer nvidia drivers, went back to nouveau.... Nevertheless i still get the problem, ..

Answer (score 0):

Fine ! I did make it !
... ubuntu wasn't involved to it at the end.
... Finally had to flash the bios.. As it wasn't an update, i did use winflash with /nodate parameter, it did make the job. You should be able to make it with unetbootin as well... but didn't try it.

Thanks to WinEunuuchs2Unix for his help !